# How do i change the font size of textOut() Win32 API in c++?

Tags: c++, winapi

Hi i would like to change the size of the output i get from textOut(). I would appreciate some help.

What im trying to output:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
    {
        std::string text = std::to_string(map[x][y]);
        TextOut(bufferHDC, mapWidth / 4 * x + mapWidth / 8, mapHeight /4*y + mapHeight/8, text.c_str(), text.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: [CreateFont/SelectObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createfontw), check the provided code sample.

Comment: @HansPassant do i just make that font object and then do selectObject() before TextOut()?

Comment: @Slynmannen Yes, `TextOut()` will use whichever `HFONT` is currently selected into the `HDC`. So create an `HFONT` with the desired characteristics, `SelectObject()` it into the `HDC` (saving the old `HFONT`), draw your text, restore the old `HFONT`, and destroy your created `HFONT`

Comment: If you need to change the size of an existing font, you can call [`GetObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getobject) on it to receive a [`LOGFONT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-logfontw) structure, manipulate the respective values as desired, and call [`CreateFontIndirectW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createfontindirectw) to create an `HFONT`. When you're done using it you'll need to clean it up by calling `DeleteObject`.